# standardizing color scale, persp() plots in panel, R

Tags: r, plot, colors, 3d

I'm creating a panel with multiple persp plots, each showing a range of data generated by tweaking predictor variables in a complex regression model. I want my 3D surface to be color coded by my z variable, which I was able to do easily enough. How do I take this color scale and make it cover the range of all z variable values that would be represented by all plots in my panel, so that the color scale between multiple persp plots can be compared?

```
#colorized z scale, only a smidge modified from http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/graphics/persp
par(bg = "white")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
x <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 30)
y <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 35)
z1 <- outer(x, y, function(a, b) a*b^2)
nrz <- nrow(z1)
ncz <- ncol(z1)
# Create a function interpolating colors in the range of specified colors
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette( c("blue", "green") )
# Generate the desired number of colors from this palette
nbcol <- 100
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- z1[-1, -1] + z1[-1, -ncz] + z1[-nrz, -1] + z1[-nrz, -ncz]
# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)
persp(x, y, z1, zlim=c(-8, 10.5), col = color[facetcol], phi = 30, theta = -30)
#zlim added to encompass combined ranges of z1 and z2

#exact same code, with different values of z
x <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 30)
y <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 35)
z2 <- outer(x, y, function(a, b) a*b^2+3)
nrz <- nrow(z2)
ncz <- ncol(z2)
# Create a function interpolating colors in the range of specified colors
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette( c("blue", "green") )
# Generate the desired number of colors from this palette
nbcol <- 100
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- z2[-1, -1] + z2[-1, -ncz] + z2[-nrz, -1] + z2[-nrz, -ncz]
# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)
persp(x, y, z2, zlim=c(-8, 10.5), col = color[facetcol], phi = 30, theta = -30)
#zlim added to encompass combined ranges of z1 and z2

#comparing the values, we see that there's different, overlapping scales from z1 and z2
summary(as.vector(z1))
summary(as.vector(z2))
```

So when you look at the two plots of z2, you see that they're on different scales, sort of. It would be a lot clearer if I could get that color scale to cover the ranges of z1 and z2[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can concatenate the two vectors (matrices) of z values before cutting, and then refer to the relevant subset of the resulting (cut) vector when specifying colour.

```
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
z1facet <- z1[-1, -1] + z1[-1, -ncz] + z1[-nrz, -1] + z1[-nrz, -ncz]
z2facet <- z2[-1, -1] + z2[-1, -ncz] + z2[-nrz, -1] + z2[-nrz, -ncz]
facetcol <- cut(c(z1facet, z2facet), nbcol)
persp(x, y, z1, zlim=c(-8, 10.5), 
      col=color[facetcol[seq_along(z1facet)]], 
      phi=30, theta=-30)
persp(x, y, z2, zlim=c(-8, 10.5), 
      col=color[facetcol[-seq_along(z1facet)]], 
      phi=30, theta=-30)
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `lattice::wireframe`, which might be simpler particularly when dealing with many surface plots:

```
library(lattice)
# First, create a named list of the surface matrices.
L <- list(z1=z1, z2=z2)

# Iterate over the elements of L, creating data.frames with row number,
#  column number, and cell value, as well as matrix name (i.e. name of 
#  the element of L).
dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(L), function(i) {
  setNames(data.frame(which(!is.na(L[[i]]), arr.ind=TRUE),
             c(L[[i]]), names(L)[i]),
           c('x', 'y', 'z', 'g'))
}))

# Plot with wireframe, faceting by `g` (the matrix name).
wireframe(z ~ x + y|g, data=dat, drape=TRUE, col.regions=color)
```

[image]

Adjust `screen` and `distance` as desired to get the look you're after, e.g.:

```
wireframe(z ~ x + y|g, data=dat, drape=TRUE, col.regions=color, 
          screen=list(z=30, x=-60), distance=0.5)
```

[image]